# ER diagram in DataModeling

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I was designing schema of toll booth system so I have an ER diagram. If anyone can help in identifying more entities and mistakes in current design.

[image]

Comment: Your ER is a mess.Why not make the relationship clear.

Comment: please tell me how to make relationship clear

Comment: Could you expand your idea on table "Toll fare", why did you exclude it as separate entity? For me looks like over-kill. Why you cant write the toll amounts direct into tables "Trip" and "Toll fare by vehicle type". By the way, common standards in table creating - table names should be in plural, like "Tables", "Users", etc. For other entities - looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

[image]

This lets you find the toll by user, and the toll by vehicle. I added a trip date because you need to know the date the vehicle rolled through the tool booth for billing purposes. I removed the many-many relation between the vehicle and the user because each vehicle (which is known to the toll system by a vehicle tag of some sort) can only have one account. Otherwise how do you know which account to charge? This has to be automated. Fares are specific to the start and end plaza and the vehicle type, but we probably want to record in the trip record specifically which booth was rolled through. So I added a Plazas table to help keep that straight. and the Effective date in the Fares table can be used to find a specific fare record based on the date of the trip. Of course your mileage may vary on this, and it is based on my limited experience driving on toll roads. You probably also want an additional table to record payments rather than the Credit table as it stands. Balance can be held in the Users table, or a separate table that maintains monthly beginning and ending balance. That along with a payment transaction table can be used to keep your customer's account accurate, and provide you a means of auditing the data without having to keep all of it on line at all times.

This is just a quick hit at this diagram, with a little thought, and the advantage of knowing your requirements, you should be able to improve on it some more. An example of missing requirements is that there are two toll schemes that I know of. In one the driver pays at each toll booth. In the other the driver gets a tick when he enters the toll road, and pays when he exist based on where he started and the vehicle class. I am guessing that you are dealing with the second type, but do you need to deal with the first type?